# Find a string within the source code (DDL) of a stored procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, string

I need to find a string in the source code (DDL) for all stored procedures in Oracle schema.

I use this query to perform the task, but I think can be improved

```
SELECT T0.OBJECT_NAME
FROM USER_PROCEDURES T0 
WHERE T0.OBJECT_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
AND INSTR( (SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE',T0.OBJECT_NAME,'MySCHEMA') 
            FROM DUAL), 'TheStringToSearch' )>0
```

is there a way of accomplishing this task in a more optimal and fast way?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you not uses packages to hold your procedures? :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, use USER_SOURCE:

```
select distinct name
from   user_source
where  type = 'PROCEDURE'
and    lower(text) like lower('%the_text_you_want%');
```

Comment: In case anyone's looking for the MS SQL version: `SELECT o.object_id, o.type_desc, o.name
from sys.objects o
where OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.object_id) like '%something%'
order by o.type_desc, o.name` (or you can use `sp_helptext` to get the definition of a single object)